# Does RabbitMQ allow Audit Logging

Tags: security, logging, messaging, amqp, audit

We need to know if RabbitMQ has security features required by our business.

Does RabbitMQ perform Audit Logging?

Does it allow encryption of its audit log?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ doesn't provide Audit Logging nor encryption of it's logs. At least out of the box. Try to look on [Firehose Tracer](http://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html) plugin, it maybe somehow close to what you want.

I guess you can also implement Audit Logging on application level, even with encryption. It won't take much time and efforts.

Comment: This feature is really needed for Management Plugin, that we can't control from application level.Access log is not much helpful regarding event logging